# Magento 2 overwrite checkout.cart.item.renderers block

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, catalog

I tried to set a new template for checkout.cart.item.renderers block and i found some issue, beucause I didn't know that i have to overwrite separately each type of product. 
I will post my solution, because maybe someone will face the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

filename :**checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor::cart/item/default.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
            <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor::cart/item/default.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
            <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.virtual">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor::cart/item/default.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
            <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.configurable">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor::cart/item/default.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
            <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.downloadable">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor::cart/item/default.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
            <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.grouped">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor::cart/item/default.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
            <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.bundle">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor::cart/item/default.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
        </body>
    </page>
```

Comment: To be more precise you can take this extension and just copy the code in this answer to the checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml. It worked for me. https://github.com/karliuka/magento2.samples/tree/master/app/code/Faonni/OverrideCartItemTemplate/view/frontend